# How can I use ggplot to graph this?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm quite new to R and I'm struggling to work out how best to graph this data. I would like to show how the evolution of membershipgood, membershipbad and membership neither across the ten years.

[Data I am trying to graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acva4.png)

I have installed the ggplot2 package and tried using a number of different tools within it but I think my data is incorrectly formatted for what I am hoping to achieve. Any help much appreciated! :)

Comment: Welcome to the site! Questions receive positive attention when they (a) are clear about the ask, (b) are easily reproducible, providing copy/pasteable sample data, and (c) demonstrate effort of what you've tried already. This question isn't doing well on any of those counts. I would suggest editing it to address those issues: For (a), what kind of graph do you want? Scatterplot? Pie chart? Faceted bar graph? What goes on the x-axis and the y-axis? If you tell us what sort of plot you want, we can help make it, but we can't tell you what you want...

Comment: For (b), we can't use a picture of data as sample input. `dput()` is a nice function for sharing sample data in a copy/pasteable way. `dput(your_data[1:10, ])` will produce R code to recreate the first 10 rows of your data. Please share that instead of a picture. For (c) - what did you try and where did you get stuck? Have you worked through an introduction to ggplot -- there are many. If you think your data is incorrectly formatted, have you tried to fix it? What did you try? You might try searching for "pivot data from wide to long" or "tidy data for ggplot".

Comment: you can paste a sample of your data with `dput(your_data[1:11])`

Comment: @K.Peltzer that will be all rows and the first 11 columns. You need a `,` in there to make it rows

Answer (score 1):

You need to pivot your data from wide format to long format to make `ggplot` easy to use. This means that instead of having three columns labeled with membership type containing values, you have one column filled with the membership type labels, and a second column containing all the actual values. You can do this with `pivot_longer` from the **tidyr** package, which along with **ggplot2**, ships with the **tidyverse** (meta)-package.

If your data frame is called `df`, then the following code should work for you:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = 'Membership') %>%
  mutate(Membership = sub('membership', '', Membership), 
         Membership = factor(Membership, c('bad', 'neither', 'good'))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, value, color = Membership)) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = NULL) +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = 'Set1') +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 16)
```

[image]

---

**Reproducible version of data from image in question - reproduced via OCR**

```r
df <- structure(list(year = 2006:2016,
               membershipgood = c(0.28, 0.26, 0.28, 0.48, 0.41, 0.35, 
                                  0.47, 0.36, 0.39, 0.25, 0.25), 
               membershipbad = c(0.85, 0.86, 0.89, 0.79, 0.91, 0.87, 
                                 0.91, 0.92, 0.87, 0.9, 0.86), 
               membershipneither = c(0.59, 0.46, 0.53, 0.62, 0.71, 
                                     0.64, 0.7, 0.6, 0.5, 0.58, 0.47)), 
          class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -11L))
```